# Routing onclick event from embedded SVG to higher level

Tags: javascript, svg, onclick

I have an HTML file that embeds two different SVG files, like so:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <object id="svg0" data="histograms.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
    <object id="svg1" data="test.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
  </body>
</html>
```

Both SVG files are interactive, by adding a javascript function that is triggered by onclick, like such:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="172pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1209 172" width="1209pt">
 <script type="text/ecmascript">
                function choose(obj) {
                  var values = [0.08,0.77];
                  var names = [ "hist_1", "hist_2", "hist_3", "hist_4", "hist_5", "hist_6", "hist_7", "hist_8", "hist_9", "hist_10", "hist_11" ];
                  for ( var i=0; i&lt;names.length; i++) {
                    var o = document.getElementById( names[i] );
                    o.style['opacity'] = values[0];
                  }
                  obj.style['opacity'] = values[1];
                }
  </script>
  ...
 <g id="figure_1">
  <g id="patch_1">
   <path d=" M0 172.8 L1209.6 172.8 L1209.6 0 L0 0 z " style="fill:#ffffff;" />
  </g>
  <g id="axes_1">
   <g cursor="pointer" id="hist_1" onclick="choose(this)">
    <path d=" M20.835 70.52 L189.696 70.52 L189.696 12.96 L20.835 12.96 z " style="fill:#ffe6cc;" />
   </g>
...
```

How can I have **a click in one SVG** file trigger javascript in **the other SVG file**? (Possibly via top level .html file as intermediate, if necessary?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing code in test.svg then top gets you the containiner, so

```
var svg0 = top.document.getElementById("svg0");
```

would get you the object element from the container document.

Then

```
obj0Document = svg0.contentDocument;
if (obj0Document && obj0Document.defaultView)
  obj0Window = obj0Document.defaultView;
else if (svg0.window)
  obj0Window  = svg0.window;
```

gets you the content's document and window.

accessing the SVG document's "window" allows you to access variables and functions defined in scripts in the SVG document.

e.g. `obj0Window.choose(something)`

Everything must have the same domain for this to work.

Comment: Can't get this to work. I get a valid svg0, a valid obj0Document, but obj0Window will simply be 'undefined.'

Comment: On what UA? I've edited the question to support a wider range.

Comment: This works now, as long as I serve them as http://. As file:// I get: 'Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.' (I'm on Opera:  OPR/34.0.2036.25)

Comment: The Chrome/Opera security model treats all files as different domains.